# ColdFusion 9 line debugger for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I see several references within Adobe's documentation regarding the line debugger.  Look here, for example:

[Set up ColdFusion to use the Debugger](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0d389-7fff.html)

I see mention of various Eclipse-related settings that I need to make.  For example (from above):

> You can determine whether the Debugger server is configured correctly
>   in Eclipse by selecting Window > Preferences > ColdFusion > RDS
>   Configuration, and then clicking Test Debugger.

However, I see no mention of what I have to do to configure my eclipse installation to get this functionality.  I assume there is an eclipse plugin I need to install.  I'm hoping that they are not actually talking about CFBuilder when they simply say "eclipse".  I should point out that I'm using vanilla eclipse with the [cfeclipse](http://cfeclipse.org) plugin (not CFBuilder).

From the CFEclipse site, I see this:

> **Debugging**
>
> Adobe released the ColdFusion 8 Extensions for Eclipse which
>   included a step debugger and RDS tools. This is no longer supported by
>   Adobe but still works in the latest CFEclipse versions.  FusionDebug
>   is a commercial step debugger available from Integral.

Can this really be true that Adobe released a free debugging extension for CF8 and eclipse, but then broke it when they went to CF9 (and offered no free alternative)?  Is there really no free way to do line debugging in CF9?

Assuming that is the case.... is there a free option for line debugging Railo? How about CF 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need: ColdFusion Builder http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder.html from Adobe, not CFEclipse.

You may install as a plugin to your existing Eclipse, or as standalone.

It can be used for free after evaluation period for free with limited features.  I'm not sure if line-debugger is one of the free features.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of the Express Edition.  From here: http://cfdocyard.blogspot.com/2011/05/coldfusion-builder-express-edition-free.html I see that one of the features exclusive to the $$$ version is "Debugging remote projects", but I'm not sure what the qualifier "remote" means in this context.  I am using CF9 Developer edition locally on the same machine as my IDE, so perhaps that would mean it is not "remote" and so I can still debug.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: From Ray Camden's blog, it appears that local debugging does work in CFBuilder Express: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/4/27/ColdFusion-Builder-2-adds-a-Free-Edition

Answer (score 7):

Using the same instructions available for CFEclipse and CF8, I was able to get the debugger working using CF9 and Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) with the CFEclipse pluggin.  After much searching, I found the RDS configuration entries live in Window->Preferences->Adobe->RDS Configuration menu option. 
How I configured it:

You have to make sure the port that the RDS Debug server starts in is open:
I am using Windows Server 2008, and  basically openned the port which I added the JVM Arguments settings in ColdFusion administrator (Otherwise Coldfusion fires it up using some randomly selected port and it could be closed which will mean it WILL NOT  accept incoming requests)  Here is the syntax:

-server -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 
-DDEBUGGER_SERVER_PORT=49208

You will have to restart Coldfusion as this is used by the JVM at startup.

In RDS Configuration I used the host name and port number of the App Server, not the Debug Server's port itself.  So in my case I am running IIS which listens on port 80 so that is the host name and port number that I used.

Now the litmus test is if you can successfully connect, then test the debugger.  If not, don't bother trying to debug an application.  On a related note, I am having some issues with breakpoints, not being hit at times,  so I am still concerned about it as a production solution, but I may be doing something wrong as well.

I have ofcourse condensed this, but the point is that it appears to be achievable.  I am new to Coldfusion so I don't know much about the options but just wanted to point out some of the configurations that once I resolved them, was able to achieve line-by-line debugging.

Comment: Richard's is really the correct answer, as the OP asked about Eclipse, not Builder (I use the former, for free). A couple of things to add: 1) I seemed to need localhost with port 830x (in my case, 8303), as myVirtualHostName with port 80 didn't seem to work. 2) I don't know if it's just Eclipse on Ubuntu/Linux, but when in the RDS configuration editing window, the actual configuration details and "Apply" button, etc. are at the bottom of a comically tall inner frame, and I must scroll (far) down to see them.

Answer (score 1):

CF9 and Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) with the CFEclipse pluggin - Apache on MacOs.
I didn't have Adobe/RDS, but I downloaded the CF801 etension for eclipse and I moved the two RDS plugin files to the Eclipse plugin directory and restarted eclipse.
After, that I had the Adobe/RDS configuration under Eclipse/preferences.
I just configured the RDS on port 80, since I have coldfusion served by local Apache, tested connection and debug and now everything seems ok. thanks
G.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend FusionDebug. It has a simpler setup and better user feature. http://www.fusion-debug.com/fd/

Comment: The problem there is that FusionDebug costs $$$ and I'm a cheap SOB.